# sending Stl containers to dll

Tags: c++, dll, stl, marshalling

Before going to the question, kindly understand my project environment.

I have a class in my DLL, which contains nested stl containers and structures as members.

By using the DLL class header files, my application is dynamically allocating memory to the dll's class object and sending it to the dll, to fill data by reading files.

Now, at tool side, I am able to get the data of structures in the class, but unable to get the data of stl container.

-> What is the reason behind this ? Is passing stl containers to dll is OK ?

### Note :

1. Both DLL and application is compiled using same code studio. Both are in 32 bit.
2. I have tried to send the container by reference and by object too. Both are not working.
3. The same code worked properly when I created a demo application before shifting the required code to the dll.
4. One more point.., When I debug the library, I can see that data is getting filled in the container, but when I comes back to the application, no data is present. One interesting fact in debugging is, Let us say I stored 3 objects in my stl containers, on debugging , when control comes back to application, I am able to see the count when I watch the variable.

   It is something like "comp | less" and remaining tags are "error".

Please consider the below code :

```
bool CMyClass::ReadHeaderData(
) {
    bool status = false;
    CMyLib *lib_obj = ((CMyClassApp*)::AfxGetApp())->GetLibObj (); 
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < 5; ++cnt) {
        CString file_path = GetFilePathOfHeader(cnt);
        if (PathFileExists(file_path)) {
            CMyEntity* entity_obj = new CMyEntity;
            if (lib_obj ->FillHeaderData(file_path, entity_obj)) {
                //some processing
                status = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return status;
}
```

Sample Entity class structure is :

```
CMyEntity {    
     struct1 {...};
     struct2 {...};
     std::map<key1, std::map<key2,value> >; 
};
```

** When I try to send the pointer reference of stl container directly to the DLL, it is working fine. The only problem is when I am trying to send it inside my class object.

If the stack frames for DLL and application are different, why the data is coming inside structures ? why it is not coming only for stl containers ?

Comment: Perhaps you need to load the PDB (symbol) files for the DLL if the DLL project is not in the same solution.

Comment: It is not in the same solution. But I have included the pdb files. I am able to debug the library too.

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to get the data of stl container."  It would be very helpful if you could show a small fragment of code (even if not complete).  Are we talking about something like:  `struct MyClass { int i; std::vector<int> vi; void loadData(); };` , and on return from the function `obj.i` is valid, but `obj.vi` is empty?

Comment: There have been bugs in the watch window regarding DLL names. What is the name of your DLL?

Comment: Please consider the attached code too.

Comment: It can only ever work properly if the DLL is built with the **exact** same compiler version and compile settings as your EXE project.  "Not in the same solution" is certainly on the top of the list of ways to blow your leg off.  Don't do it.

Comment: My application and dll are compiled with same compiler, and the settings are also same.

Comment: @BharadwajGali: the settings must be the same down to the compilation mode (debug/release - in VC++ the memory layout of STL containers changes completely); also, you must link against the dll version of the CRT on both sides.

Comment: (in general, having STL objects - or any "complex" C++ object - at dll boundaries is enough of a PITA ABI-wise that you typically want to avoid it, period)

Comment: Hi @MatteoItalia . I am unable understand why only stl containers memory layout is different. Can you please share necessary info for understanding this, if possible?.  And How can I avoid this situation now ? I have multiple levels of data. what can be the best method make this design work ?

Comment: Because in debug mode they have additional runtime checks that alter their memory layout (as in, there's an `#ifdef` that provides a completely different implementation that includes very thorough checks). It is possible to disable it, though.